# Magento 2.2.5 Customer Registration Page Reloads After clicking the Create Account Button

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2

I have a fresh installation of magento 2.2.5 with Magetigue theme and I have migrated the data from magento 1.9.3.7 to magento 2.2.5 using data migration tool. Now when I try to create an account by entering all the fields and click the create button, It reloads the same registration page showing an error message that `" "" is a required Field"`. I have checked the `app/design/frontend/THEME_VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml` file and it contains the form key

```
<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

So, its not a form key problem
I have deleted all the cookies too, but still no luck.

I have traced the post request after clicking the create customer button in the network tab and the post request goes to **CreatePost.php** in `/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php` and the request status is 302 found.

I have added a log code in **CreatePost.php**

And found that the problem lies in this code:

```
try {
            $address = $this->extractAddress();
            $addresses = $address === null ? [] : [$address];

            $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $this->_request);
            $customer->setAddresses($addresses);

            $password = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password');
            $confirmation = $this->getRequest()->getParam('password_confirmation');
            $redirectUrl = $this->session->getBeforeAuthUrl();

            $this->checkPasswordConfirmation($password, $confirmation);

            $customer = $this->accountManagement
                ->createAccount($customer, $password, $redirectUrl);
```

Can somebody help resolve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the issue, I found that the problem was with the `rp_token` field of customer_entity table. When I tried to edit the customer from backend it shows the same error i.e. " `"" is a required field` ", but when I click the reset password button first and then click the save customer button it doesn't show any error and the customer gets saved. The reset password sets the value of `rp_token` field in the `customer_entity` table. In order to make it work I edited the
`vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Validator/Attribute/Data.php` File and edited the isValid($entity) function as:

```
public function isValid($entity)
{
    /** @var $attributes Attribute[] */
    $attributes = $this->_getAttributes($entity);

    $data = [];
    if ($this->_data) {
        $data = $this->_data;
    } elseif ($entity instanceof \Magento\Framework\DataObject) {
        $data = $entity->getData();
    }

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();

         if($attributeCode == "rp_token" || $attributeCode == "rp_token_created_at"){
            continue;
        }


        if (!$attribute->getDataModel() && !$attribute->getFrontendInput()) {
            continue;
        }
        $dataModel = $this->_attrDataFactory->create($attribute, $entity);
        $dataModel->setExtractedData($data);
        if (!isset($data[$attributeCode])) {
            $data[$attributeCode] = null;
        }
        $result = $dataModel->validateValue($data[$attributeCode]);
        if (true !== $result) {
            $this->_addErrorMessages($attributeCode, (array)$result);
        }
    }
    return count($this->_messages) == 0;
}
```

Though editing the core files of Magento is not a good convention. But just to make it work I edited this function and It worked.

P.S: A better solution will be to create a module that will override this function...